# Active Record Dirty doesn't show changes for nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that sends the params for a date field (`collected`) as:

> "Invalid Date" if date is not set
>
> "Some Actual date" if date is set

**CODE**

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:collected, :ticket_number)
end

def list
  t = Ticket.new
  t.assign_attributes(ticket_params)

  if t.changes["ticket_number"].present?
    # Do something and build to save to DB
  end

  # Problem is here
  if t.changes["collected"].present?
    # Do something and build to save to DB
  end
end
```

**NOTE:** `collected` is **datetime** field and `ticket_number` is **integer** field

Now, For Example

if `collected: "2019-01-09T00:00:00-05:00", ticket_number: "null"`
then `t.changes` gives

```
{"ticket_number"=>[nil, 0], "collected"=>[nil, Wed, 09 Jan 2019 00:00:00 -0500]}
```

But, similarly if `collected: "Invalid Date", ticket_number: "null"`
then `t.changes` would give

```
{"ticket_number"=>[nil, 0]}
```

Now, I want to know when the date was set as Invalid, but `t.changes` doesn't return any information about `collected` field changes

**NOTE :** I can't go by directly checking params values, I'm bound to go ahead with `t.changes` (Active Record Dirty) way

I apologise if the question is confusing. My primary goal is to bring `collected` onto Active Record dirty

Comment: `# Do something and Save to DB` ? You saved ?

Comment: @ray By that I meant, I'm building up params to save to DB. Otherwise, if I saved then `changes` won't work as expected

Comment: `assign_attributes` returns the attributes after the typecast because of which `collected` returns nothing since it wasn't able to parse the change at all. At this point, you can only retrieve the value with `t.read_attribute_before_type_cast(:collected)` to read what was the original value supplied.

Comment: @kiddorails You are right about `assign_attributes`, but, my expectation is, is there a way to get `collected` within Active Record Dirty? Eg: I did the hack to pass "null" as `ticket_number` so the `changes` catches it as `{"ticket_number"=>[nil, 0]}`

Comment: My answer could explain what you know but did not provide solution so deleted! I do not see any alternative perhaps you can use trick provided by @kiddorails somehow